# DAX measure to iterate each row for correct division (for total as well)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, dax, measure

I am not sure if there's a way in DAX to create a measure that would help me with the following:

- Calculate the efficiency by day
- Display the total efficiency in a pivot table / PowerBI matrix as the overall total and not as sum of the daily efficiency

Here's a simple example:
[image]

Where:

- `Total Categories = Category1 + Category2 + Category3`
- `Efficiency = (Total Categories + Category4*0.33)/Category4`

At first I've created measures for each category (e.g. `TotalCateg1 = SUM[Category1]` etc.) and hopping to get the right result in the end. My problem is I am not able to get both the daily efficiency and the total right. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Total Categories use this formula:

`=SUM([Category 1])+SUM([Category 2])+SUM([Category 3])` .

then for the Efficiency use this formula:

`=([Total Categories]+SUM([Category 4])*0.33)/SUM([Category 4])`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Kresimir! Excellent answer. I can't believe I got it so wrong the first time. Hats off to you!